# How can I test the syntax on SQL Server 2005 without install it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, version

I am using SQL Server 2008. Everything goes right in my local development.

But when I deploy the program and the stored procedure into client workstation which is using SQL Server 2005, errors are showing up.

I believe it is caused by the syntax problem between SQL Server 2005 and 2008 because I have fixed some of the parts and it can be fixed. It is quite time consuming when I using SQL Server 2008 and search the error one by one in the forum.

So is there any way I can use the SQL Server 2005 editor to write stored procedure without install it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could create a test database and set it's **compatibility level** to **90** (SQL Server 2005). Any syntax that's not supported by SQL Server 2005 should be called out in this case.

Comment: SQL server express 2005 is fee to downlaod and use. Is there any restriction about not installing express edition. Yes it has limitation of max 4 G database http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844

Comment: @marc_s
would you mind explain more how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **compatibility level** of your database, you can create a database in SQL Server 2008, but then make it look, feel and act like SQL Server **2005**.

Steps:

1. Create your database - either visually or with

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE MySampleDB
   ```

   This creates a database on your server, in the default compatibility level as defined by the `model` database on your server. On a SQL Server **2008** machine, this typically will be a compatibility level of `100`.
2. Check the compatibility level:

   ```
   USE MySampleDB
   GO
   SELECT name, compatibility_level
   FROM sys.databases
   WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
   ```
3. Now set the compatibility level to `90` to emulate a SQL Server **2005** database:

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE MySampleDB
   SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
   ```

Now, you have a `MySampleDB` that is acting and looking like SQL Server 2005 - any T-SQL constructs that are not available in SQL Server 2005 should cause problems and errors in this database, too! (e.g. the `DATE` datatype or other things)

Comment: Thanks for your update. I will test it later. Once it is fine, I will markup as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Please note that, to allow level 90 (2005), you need to have a Maximum of SQL 2012 installed. Versions after that can't fall back to 2005 compatibility. See this list to see which version supports which fallback: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

You can also use [Vertabelo](http://www.vertabelo.com/), which is very simple. It will generate query for designed tables automatically.

Comment: These two online platform are awesome but both of them did not support SQL 2005. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: sqlfiddle supports only from 2008 version

Comment: Yes. I know it but my client working environment is in SQL 2005.